# how to make character counter excluding white space and line space?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-edittext

[image]

as you can see in the image above, I have multiline edittext and a words counter textview in the bottom right corner.

I expect that the counter will show number '7' as per the number of character input in the edit text. So I want to exclude white space and also line space (enter, \n) to be counted in the word counter.

but unfortunately I get '9' instead of '7'. here is the code I use:

```
class CreateEventDescriptionFragment : Fragment() {

    lateinit var fragmentView : View
    lateinit var inputEventDescriptionEditText : EditText
    lateinit var wordsCounterTextView: TextView

    lateinit var mContext : Context
    lateinit var mActivity : FragmentActivity

    override fun onAttach(context: Context) {
        super.onAttach(context)

        mContext = context
        activity?.let { mActivity = it }

    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        fragmentView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_create_event_description, container, false)

        setUpViewsDeclaration()
        setUpListeners()


        return fragmentView
    }


    private fun setUpViewsDeclaration() {
        inputEventDescriptionEditText = fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.editText_event_description_input)
        wordsCounterTextView = fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.textView_words_counter_event_description)
    }


    private fun setUpListeners() {

        inputEventDescriptionEditText.addTextChangedListener(object: TextWatcher {
            override fun afterTextChanged(s: Editable?) {

                setWordsCounter(s)
                wordsCounterTextView.text = "$numberOfInputWords"

            }

            override fun beforeTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, count: Int, after: Int) {

            }

            override fun onTextChanged(s: CharSequence?, start: Int, before: Int, count: Int) {

                setWordsCounter(s)
                wordsCounterTextView.text = "$numberOfInputWords"

            }

        })

    }

    private fun setWordsCounter(words: CharSequence?) {

        val rawInputString = words.toString().trim()
        val removedEmptyLineInputString = rawInputString.replace("(?m)^[ \t]*\r?\n", "")
        val removedEmptySpaceInputString = removedEmptyLineInputString.replace(" ", "")

        numberOfInputWords = removedEmptySpaceInputString.count()

    }



}
```

Java is Ok. what went wrong in here ?

Comment: Did you try this : var length = editText.text.length

Comment: Maybe your regex is wrong?

Comment: This will catch spaces and new lines: `[\n\r\s]+`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I solved it changing your method to this one :

```
private fun setWordsCounter(words: CharSequence?) {
    val rawInputString = words.toString()
        .trim()
        .replace(" ","")
        .replace("\n","")
    numberOfInputWords = rawInputString.length
}
```

What it does it, first `trim()` - Remove all of white spaces, and then remove all of `new lines`.

And the output is this one :

[image]

Comment: what if there is a space in between?

Comment: use \s to catch all whitespace characters. instead of " "